# Python Equivalent of HTML5 Canvas

Tags: python, html, canvas, tkinter, html5-canvas

How would I accomplish the following HTML5 canvas stroke using Python? Would I use [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)? Qt? WxWidgets? Some other library?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(20,100);
ctx.lineTo(70,100);
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.stroke();

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tkinter use can use the `Canvas` widget type. You can't directly change the color of the border; I'm not sure if that's part of the question or not. You can easily draw a colored border, or put it inside a colored frame to give it a border.

To create the line, use the `create_line` method.

Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=300, height=150,borderwidth=1)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        points = (20,20,20,100,70,100)
        self.canvas.create_line(points, fill="red")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! No, the border color is irrelevant, but that's useful information.

Comment: This is a totally separate question, but can the canvas be saved as SVG?

Comment: @MarkRichman: there is no built-in support for svg, but the objects on the canvas are objects rather than pixmaps, and the canvas has good introspection capabilities. It should be pretty straight-forward to convert the contents of the canvas to SVG. I've seen it done in Tcl (eg: http://wiki.tcl.tk/4534), but I haven't seen it done in python.