# Implementing html5 graphics(canvas) in python GUI

Tags: python, html, user-interface

Is it possible to implement html5 graphics element into python GUI and if so which package would you recommend?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: PyCairo is  similar to canvas, that's maybe what you need ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Equivalent of HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553307/python-equivalent-of-html5-canvas)